How do I change the text below "Recurring Total" in WooCommerce?
here is what I am referring to:

Where it currently says "First renewal: May 6, 2025" - I'd like to change that text. I assume its something I can do in PHP, but I'm not sure where to find / how to fix.

Figured it out - found the function in wcs-cart-functions.php
function wcs_add_cart_first_renewal_payment_date( $order_total_html, $cart ) {
    if ( 0 !== $cart->next_payment_date ) {
            $first_renewal_date = date_i18n( wc_date_format(), wcs_date_to_time( get_date_from_gmt( $cart->next_payment_date ) ) );
            // translators: placeholder is a date
            $order_total_html  .= '<div class="first-payment-date"><small>' . sprintf( __( 'First renewal: %s', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ), $first_renewal_date ) .  '</small></div>';
        }

        return $order_total_html;
    }
    add_filter( 'wcs_cart_totals_order_total_html', 'wcs_add_cart_first_renewal_payment_date', 10, 2 );

Changing 'First renewal: ' to whatever you want it to be.
